# passar uma variavel entre duas pagínas com PHP

Tags: php

eu envio o formulario para a pagina recebeformulario e quero usar a mesma variavel na outra pagina recebevariavel.

index.php

```
<form action="recebeformulario.php" method="POST">

<div class="form-group">
<label for="idTracao">Placa:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="idTracao" placeholder="Tração" name='nmTracao' pattern="[A-Za-z]{3}[0-9]{1}[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{2}|[A-Za-z]{3}[0-9]{4}" maxlength="7" minlength="7" required>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="row">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Enviar.</button>
</div>
</form>
```

O formulário é recebido na pagina recebeformulario.php

```
<?php
$idTracao = $_POST['idTracao'];
echo"$idTracao";
?>
```

E o meu problema está aqui na pagina recebevariavel.php eu quero apenas a variavel inserida no formulário.

```
<?php
include('recebeformulario.php');
        
$nmTracao=$_POST['nmTracao'];
$nome = "$nmTracao" . str_pad($indice, 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
echo"$nome";
?>
```

Eu quero inserir a placa AAA9A99 e transformar em AAA9A99001

Comment: acho que você consegue passar essa informação pelo menos de 2 formas. 1 - Usando sessão `$_SESSION[]` ou talvez tenha que trafegar essas informações via `$_GET[]`/ `Query Strings`

Comment: William obrigado. porém preciso enviar o formulário por POST.  meu projeto está funcionando perfeitamente. porém a imagem é renomeada para imagem001, imagem002 e assim por diante.  preciso do array placa para renomear as imagens ficando assim:  AAA1A11000 - AAA1A11001 - AAA1A11002 e quando a placa muda fica assim BBB2B22000.

Answer (score -1):

Rodrygo, seu código e explicação, são bem confusos, mas tentarei te ajudar.

Rodrygo, no input, quando setar os parâmetros **name** e **id**, utilize aspas duplas. Isso foi a primeira coisa que o vscode reclamou.

Segundo, no input que você está passando o parâmetro **name** como o valor de "**nmTracao**", mas na sua página **recebeformulario.php** você está esperando pelo parametro "**idTracao**". No input é recomendável que o parâmetro **name** tenha o nome do **id**.

Terceiro e Quarto, no seu código da página recebevariavel.php, você está usando o seguinte código:

```
<?php
include('recebeformulario.php');
        
$nmTracao=$_POST['nmTracao'];
$nome = "$nmTracao" . str_pad($indice, 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
echo"$nome";
?>
```

Na linha 4 você criar a variável **$nmTracao** e passa pra função, um índice/variável (**$indice**) que nem existe. Fora o fato que você está passado os parâmetros de maneira equivocada.

Na documentação oficial do PHP, [str_pad](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-pad.php) funciona da seguinte maneira:

```
<?php
str_pad(A STRING A SER MODIFICADA,TAMANHO FINAL EM INTEIRO QUE VOCÊ QUER QUE A STRING TENHA AO FINAL APOS A EXECUCAO DA FUNCAO, O QUE QUER QUE SEJA INCREMETADO NA STRING, ONDE QUE O INCREMENTO SERÁ POSICIONADO)
?>
```

Na própria documentação também informa:

```
Se o valor de pad_length é negativo ou menor do que o tamanho da string , não há nenhum preenchimento.
```

Partindo de como a função funciona, o tamanho da string que você informou no exemplo e a quantidade de incremento e o lado a ser incrementado, o código precisa ser assim:

```
<?php
$nome = str_pad($nmTracao, 10, "0", STR_PAD_RIGHT);
?>
```

Modifiquei o seu código e ele ficou assim (eu removi a página recebevariavel da equação):

**index.php**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="idTracao">Placa:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="idTracao" placeholder="Tração" name="idTracao" pattern="[A-Za-z]{3}[0-9]{1}[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{2}|[A-Za-z]{3}[0-9]{4}" maxlength="7" minlength="7" required>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="row">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Enviar.</button>
</div>
```

**recebeformulario.php**

```
<?php

$nmTracao = $_POST['idTracao'];
$nome = str_pad($nmTracao, 10, "0", STR_PAD_RIGHT);
echo $nome;
?>
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).